# Multiple conditions in for-loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I want to loop through a data frame to check if one statement is stratified (before checking elif, I want the code goes through all the K values and if it is not satisfied check the elif):
I have the following data frame:

```
z={'speed':[2.2,12.74,5.1,.91,8.9]}
data=pd.DataFrame(data=z)
```

I want to select the row which has speed less than 5 and previous speed is also less than 5. if this statement is not satisfied, I want the code finds the first point (backwards) which has speed less than 5
this is the code I've wrote but it has syntax error and I'm not sure if the code goes through all k to check the first statement and then check the second one in case the first one is not satistfied:

```
for k in reversed(data.index[:-1]):
if (data['speed'][k]<5 and data['speed'][k-1]<5):
    print(k)
break
elif data['speed'][k]<5:
    print(k)
break
```

the outcome of this should be 3, since the first statement is not satisfied
Thank you for your help

Comment: break is not indented properly. The elif is pretty much unreachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `break` statement indentation is not correct. The code is always breaking the loop at the first `break`.
The code should be like this:

```
import pandas as pd
z={'speed':[2.2, 2.74, 5.1, 9.1, 0.5]}
data=pd.DataFrame(data=z)

found = 0

for k in range(len(data['speed']) - 1, 0, -1):
    if (data['speed'][k]<5 and data['speed'][k-1]<5):
       print(k)
       found = 1
       break
    
if found == 0:
    for k in range(len(data['speed']) - 1, -1, -1):
        if data['speed'][k]<5:
           print(k)
           break
```

Comment: Thanks. I also face another problem with this code. First I want the code to check the first if statement for all the K, if it is not satisfied then checks the elif. But this code, basically checks the first if statement for each K and if it was not true checks the elif. But what I want is to check the first if for all the k and then if it was not true checks the elif. What do you think I can do in this case?

Comment: Can you please add the output you want for a particular input? @yosi

Comment: sure. consider this input    :z={'speed':[2.2,2.74,5.1,9.1,0.5]}
data=pd.DataFrame(data=z). I want the code showing me index 1 which is related to 2.74

Comment: Why should your code show index 1? Can you please explain? @yosi

Comment: yeah. So I want to write the code in a way that the main if statement looks at the this expression (data['speed'][k]<5 and data['speed'][k-1]<5) for all the K that I have. if there was no K to satisfy this condition, then look at this statement: data['speed'][k]<5     for the example I mentioned in my last comment since the first and main condition is satisfied I do not want to consider the second one and need output 1 which is 2.74

Comment: Then you have to use two for loops. I also changed the for loop syntax as your one would give ```KeyError```.
Please check the updated code. If it is what you wanted, mark the answer as accepted. @yosi